# input field changes once i enter input

Tags: css, forms, input

I have a form which uses tabs. Any time input is entered into the text input box the padding changes, I cannot work out what is causing this.

I tried setting margins and padding with !important to see if i could control it, but this was not successful.

Comment: right button on your input, inspect in dev tools. check the value, mainly those with "user agent stylesheet". Check before any input and after. Perhaps something coming from there

Comment: Can you provide us your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.